# How to start making an Audio and Video Streaming Application in c#

Tags: c#

where can i start my audio/video streaming.. like for example im playing a music on my desktop home and i can listen my music at work through media player via IP..

i just want to develop my own audio streaming server using c#..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on you're requirements .
If you need only to stream Windows Media Format (WMV) than WME SDK should solve the issue - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23848 .
If you need to stream in several Formats and Codec than you can use VLC Media Player ActiveX which is easy to integrate and stream using it .
Using VLC you have option's like Transcode ,Preview ,Multicast ,UDP/TCP etc.
http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

**[EDIT]**
If you need help using VLC ,i can provide some Examples.

To start working with VLC ActiveX you should first install the latest VLC Player from VideoLan.
Than go to VisualStudio - ToolBox - (RightClick) Choose Item .
Than from COM Component's tab chose VideoLAN VLC ActiveX Plugin v2 . Drag anywhere into the form .

code:
    //The First Param. Can be a FileName ,Another Network Stream IP or the Cd/DvD Drive
    //The thir Param. should be the Option's you want to use which you can read from http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html

```
vlc.playlist.add("FileName/Stream IP/Drive Letter","Display Text", "Options");

vlc.playlist.play();
```

Here is also another article using VLC ActiveX - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/LiquidVideo.aspx

Comment: yes, can i see some examples? i tried this link  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23848 but their examples are not working well when i convert it to latest..

Comment: @vrynzent i updated my question ,check it and tell us if it's working or not !